# Does iOS SDK keeps the connection alive between Cloud Code Function calls?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, websocket

I'm implementing an autocomplete functionallity in a mobile app. I plan to have an `autocomplete` function on Parse Cloud Code but I'm afraid of the latency/delay that could bring up.

Specifically I would like to know how is calling parse Cloud Functions compared to do calls to a regular webserver over a WebSocket connection.

NOTE: I see the iOS SDK call to Parse functions uses NSURLSession which will leverage KeepAlive by default. What I don't know if the server copes up with that.

Comment: Like everyone else who uses Parse for awhile ......... make the change to PubNub, Pusher or Firebase, or similar!  Or, combine those with Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud functions can be done both sync and async however they are very stingy about how long the connection stays open.  In other-words you'd have to separate api calls. So, your answer is no.

Also, I might mention this from their guide on iOS cloud code calls

> There is a limit of 8 concurrent httpRequests per Cloud Code request, and additional requests will be queued up.

This means that even if you somehow forced the connection to stay open like a WebSocket...you couldn't have more than 8 people using that view/cloud function at a time or everyone else wouldn't be able to access the function.

However, Ive dealt with this myself and you have a few options....

1)Make your own SocketIO server that make rest requests to parses cloud code functions. Theres even a iOS SDK from SocketIO now. So this is a pretty easy option.

2)Accept that youll have a pretty high API call rate and keep making it.

3)Do what I did and Call all the objects you need at the beginning and have iOS perform the autocomplete on the fly. Heres a helpful search on cocoa controls that should give you a head start to get it handled check it out [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=autocomplete). Any one of these would save you hours of time of trying to sort through and repopulate yourself. If you have a lot of objects you need to get. Remember if you are returning more than 100 results(the default return amount) set query.limit = 1000(max return limit).